# Browser in protractor test closes automatically

Tags: javascript, jasmine, timeout, protractor

I have been running a protractor test that closes mid test. I am using jasmine with protractor. The defaultTimeoutInterval is set to `defaultTimeoutInterval: 8000000`, the allScriptsTimeout is set to `allScriptsTimeout: 10000000`. My tests take almost an hour to run for each `it()` statement. This is because they are waiting on certain objects to appear. When I increase some of my internal times to make the objects appear quicker, the browsers dont close. But this causes the tests to fail as I need to wait for an extended period of time. So what is happening is that the browsers are closing on their own, mid test. I have 4 browser instances running. The first browserInstance closes after 35 minutes, the second one closes 5 minutes after. I still need these browsers to continue running the tests.  I do not have `browser.close()` anywhere in my code and I do nothing to prompt them to close. This is the only error that I get:

> System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
>     Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>         at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:10)
>         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:639:15)
>         at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:538:13)
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:472:11
>         at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
>         at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
>         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
>         at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
>     From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, i.glyphicon-bell)
>         at WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:377:17)
>         at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:236:28)
>         at runWaitForAngularScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:264:30)
>         at ProtractorBrowser.waitForAngular (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:270:16)
>         at ElementArrayFinder.getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:155:29)
>         at ElementArrayFinder.getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:261:56)
>         at ElementArrayFinder.ElementFinder.getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:717:39)
>         at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:407:34)
>         at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:101:30)
>         at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:742:22)Error
>         at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:406:27)
>         at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:101:30)
>         at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:742:22)
>         at /Users/Harman/webapp-qa-tests/js/tests/brackets/4-player-bracket.js:203:64
>         at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
>         at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
>         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
>         at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
>     From: Task: Run it("should allow player 1 to concede") in control flow
>         at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:16:5
>         at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
>         at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
>         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
>         at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
>     From asynchronous test: 
>     Error
>         at Suite. (/Users/Harman/webapp-qa-tests/js/tests/brackets/4-player-bracket.js:189:9)
>         at Suite. (/Users/Harman/webapp-qa-tests/js/tests/brackets/4-player-bracket.js:126:5)
>         at Object. (/Users/Harman/webapp-qa-tests/js/tests/brackets/4-player-bracket.js:13:1)

I am running `webdriver 2.24`, newest version of chrome, with protractor `version 4.0.9`

I have removed the ip address and host name from the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core problem is **you are trying to run on latest browser using old selenium version**.It should be 2.53.x something.

Please upgrade your protractor version to latest like 4.0.11 by changing the version in package.json file and do from command prompt(inside project root directory):

```
npm update
```

and then give update your selenium driver with following command from command prompt

```
webdriver-manager update
```

it will update the selenium version to latest and then try running your tests again.